# formGroup.get vs formGroup.controls in reactive form - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Is there any preferred way when selecting validation using

- `myForm.controls['name'].valid`
- `myForm.get('name').valid`

as both seems to be only syntactically different but achieving the same goal.

```
<label>Name
  <input type="text" formControlName="name">
</label>
<div class="alert" *ngIf="!myForm.controls['name'].valid && myForm.controls['name'].touched">
  {{ titleAlert }}
</div>
```

Same as

```
<div class="alert" *ngIf="!myForm.get('name').valid && myForm.get('name').touched">
  {{ titleAlert }}
</div>
```

From what I checked in the code, `get` has this code:

```
AbstractControl.prototype.get = function (path) { return _find(this, path, '.'); };
```

I have just started Angular, so an expert opinion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Just like what you have found, `FormGroup.get` is designed to access target formcontrol by it's `path`. And it's more often used for complicated(*multi layer embed*) situation, which makes it easy to get the target control from multi layer embed form and also makes code clear and easily to understand.

Take below as a example, you can simply access the first element of the embed FormArray by `this.form.get('test.0')` instead of `this.form.controls.test.controls[0]`:

```typescript
this.form = this.formBuilder.group(
  {
    test: this.formBuilder.array(
      [
        ['form control 1 in form array'],
        ['form control 1 in form array'],
        ...
      ]
    )
  }
);
```

Comment: Though it is recommended to create a getter function, in order to avoid using such a syntax over and over.

    `get nestedFormArray(): FormArray {
        return this.heroForm.get('nestedFormArray') as FormArray;
    };`

Comment: You should make your answer a little clearer that the real answer is: "it depends". But still a good explanation bc I learned something new!

Answer (score 10):

This question is related to: [Will using Angular Reactive Forms .get() method in template cause unnecessary method calls like a component method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62033196/will-using-angular-reactive-forms-get-method-in-template-cause-unnecessary-me).

In templates I prefer using `myForm.controls.name` to avoid the `myForm.get('name')` function call. If the field selector is very complex, then I would store the field in a component attribute so in the template its access is instant.

In controllers it shouldn't matter too much using one or another.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO if you are using **typed forms** is better using

```
myForm.controls.controlName
```

In this case if you have a control that is of type FormGroup or FormArray you don't need to cast it to a type

```
((this.form.get('arrayControl') as FormArray).at(index) as FormGroup).contains(controlName)
```

you can write just this

```
this.form.controls.arrayControl.at(index).contains(controlName)
```