# Angular 7 setting values of reactive form on component load enable save button even if the form isn't validated

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular7

I have the following issue. [Click to check the stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-reactive-form-3d19rq).

I am setting a reactive form in the constructor:

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      'family_name_en': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'family_name_ar': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[\u0600-\u06FF ]*')]),
      'unit_id': new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, [Validators.required])
});
```

And in the `ngOnInti()` hook, I am getting the data related to the `unit_id`.

As I am migrating data from platform to another, the family name in arabic was not recommended, but it is now. So most of the data will load without the arabic name.

The issue is the button is always enabled, and what I need to do is if a user wants to update this `unit_id`, he should add the arabic name so the button is enabled then.

If the form is valid, no harm enabling the button on load of the component.

Here is the `getData()` method that get the data and set the form group controls values:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getDataById();
}
```

getDataById():

```
getDataById() {
    this.showSpinner = true;
    this.auth.getDataById(this.unit_id).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        if (data['info'][0]['total'] == 1) {
          this.noDataBool = false;
          this.showSpinner = false;
          this.family_name_en = data['info'][0]['hh_last_name_en'];
          this.formGroup.controls['family_name_en'].setValue(this.family_name_en);
          this.family_name_ar = data['info'][0]['hh_last_name_ar'];
          this.formGroup.controls['family_name_ar'].setValue(this.family_name_ar);
          this.unit_id = data['info'][0]['unit_id'];
          this.formGroup.controls['unit_id '].setValue(this.unit_id);
    }
}
```

The button:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="updateData()" [disabled]="!formGroup.valid">
    <mat-icon>update</mat-icon>Update
</button>
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a minimal sample stackblitz replicating this issue?

Comment: How to simulate the getDataById() ?

Comment: You can simply create a method on your component and return some static data that you are expecting from this method for that.

Comment: @SiddAjmera Okay I will work on it now.

Comment: here is a stack blitz @SiddAjmera https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-reactive-form-3d19rq

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of directly accessing the `FormControl`s by using `controls` on the `formGroup`, you should use the `get` API on them. This would give you more control and significantly clean up your implementation(especially in case of getting deeply nested elements). You can change the Component Implementation like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  formGroup: FormGroup;
  titleAlert: string = 'This field is required';
  post: any = '';
  family_name_en;
  family_name_ar;
  unit_id;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      'family_name_en': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'family_name_ar': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[\u0600-\u06FF ]*')]),
      'unit_id': new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, [Validators.required])
    });
    this.getDataById();
  }

  getDataById() {
    let data: Array<any> = [
      'Ali', '', '123'
    ]
    this.family_name_en = data[0];
    this.formGroup.get('family_name_en').setValue(this.family_name_en);
    this.family_name_ar = data[1];
    this.formGroup.get('family_name_ar').setValue(this.family_name_ar);
    this.unit_id = data[2];
    this.formGroup.get('unit_id').setValue(this.unit_id);
  }

}
```

Here's an [**Updated StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-reactive-form-iuwpte?file=app/app.component.ts) for your ref. You can test it by typing in `علي` in there which would enable the Update button. Typing `Ali` will let it stay disabled.

Comment: What is the difference between `get()` and `.constrols[].setValue()` ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642926/formgroup-get-vs-formgroup-controls-in-reactive-form-angular) should give you a pretty good idea about it.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the following code in situations like this:

```
this.family_name_ar.setValue(data['info'][0]['hh_last_name_ar']);
this.family_name_ar.updateValueAndValidity();
```

By calling the second method, `updateValueAndValidity()` we tell Angular to

> Recalculate the value and validation status of the control.

More info on the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity).

Now, the button should be disabled and the form invalid if the `data['info'][0]['hh_last_name_ar']` is empty.

You can use the methods above for every field you need.

Comment: It's a method on type `AbstractControl`.

Comment: @MihailStancescu I tried it and the button still disabled as `[disabled]="!formGroup.valid" is always false

Comment: You have to do what I said for all the controls.